# Sequence save of .dat files in matlab

Tags: matlab

I try to save the each step results into sequence format. i.e.

```
cm_clusters_2_00001.dat
cm_clusters_2_00002.dat
cm_clusters_2_00003.dat
.
.
.
cm_clusters_2_00020.dat
```

"particles_file_name" show me the required file name in correct format but when it save that file it write "particles_file_name" and that is why i am over writing my results under the same name.

Part of code which generate sequence names:

```
for kk= 1:20 
    if(kk<10)
        file_number = ['0000' int2str(kk)];
    elseif(kk>=10 && kk<100)
        file_number = ['000' int2str(kk)];
    elseif(kk>=100 && kk<1000)
        file_number = ['00' int2str(kk)];
    elseif(kk>=1000 && kk<10000)
        file_number = ['0' int2str(kk)];
    end

    particles_file_name = ['cm_clusters_2_' file_number '.dat'];

    save ('particles_file_name')

 end;
```

any body suggest me the the correct way how to save these file so its not over written under the same name. As code show the correct name

```
 particles_file_name = ['cm_clusters_2_' file_number '.dat'];
```

but Save it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change:

```
save('particles_file_name')
```

to

```
save(particles_file_name)
```

`particles_file_name` is your variable with the changing file name, so you need to pass it directly to the `save` command. What you are doing instead is passing a string `'particles_file_name'` which has no relation whatsoever with the variable `particles_file_name`.