# Saving results Sequence wise in .dat format

Tags: matlab

i try to save the results in .dat format by sequence wise increasing name. but end up in wrong format/file name.

```
1st loop result    
 cm_clusters_2=[ 0.0293650000000000 0.0562520000000000]

2nd loop result
 cm_clusters_2=[ 0.0293650000000000 0.0562520000000000; 0.0293650000000000 0.0562520000000000]

3rt loop result
 cm_clusters_2=[ 0.0293650000000000 0.0562520000000000; 0.0293650000000000 0.0562520000000000;      
                0.0293650000000000 0.0562520000000000]
 .
 .
 .
10th loop result
 cm_clusters_2= [0.0293650000000000 0.0562520000000000; 0.0293650000000000 0.0562520000000000;      
                0.0293650000000000 0.0562520000000000; 0.0293650000000000 0.0562520000000000;  
                0.0293650000000000 0.0562520000000000; 0.0293650000000000 0.0562520000000000;
                0.0293650000000000 0.0562520000000000; 0.0293650000000000 0.0562520000000000;  
                0.0293650000000000 0.0562520000000000; 0.0293650000000000 0.0562520000000000]
```

Sequence numbering format:

```
 if(kk<10)
     file_number = ['0000' int2str(kk)];
 elseif(kk>=10 && kk<100)
    file_number = ['000' int2str(kk)];
 elseif(kk>=100 && kk<1000)
    file_number = ['00' int2str(kk)];
 elseif(kk>=1000 && kk<10000)
    file_number = ['0' int2str(kk)];
 end
```

I already try these three formats by changing the saving file name but in 1st format file save under the name of "particles_file_name" and other or not working

```
 if kk~=1

    particles_file_name = ['cm_clusters_2_' file_number.dat];

    save particles_file_name  cm_clusters_2 -ASCII ;

 end
```

2nd format

```
 if kk~=1

    particles_file_name = ['cm_clusters_2_' file_number];

    save particles_file_name.dat  cm_clusters_2 -ASCII ;

 end
```

3rd format

```
 if kk~=1

    save ( ['cm_clusters_2_' file_number.dat] cm_clusters_2 -ASCII ;

 end
```

Any command line which can save my data file in .dat format and sequence wise increase in the saving file name.

From my past question i will not get the desire sequence file name updated that is why i write this question with my data all my resuts are saved in under the same name("particles_file_name")
 which is not appropriate for my results. 
 [Sequence save of .dat files in matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26296146/sequence-save-of-dat-files-in-matlab)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try [formatting strings](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/formatting-strings.html#bq05n1r-1) with [`sprintf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html)

```
particles_file_name = sprintf('cm_clusters_2_%05d.dat', kk );
save( particles_file_name, '-ASCII', 'cm_clusters_2' );
```

The format string `'%05d'` will give you an int with at least 5 digits padded with zeros if `kk` has less than 5 digits.

You might also want to consider replacing `int2str` with [`num2str`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2str.html) that allows you to format the string

```
file_number = num2str( kk, '%05d' );
```

Againg, using the same format string.